# Call of overloaded function is ambiguous... But Why? Template problem

Tags: c++

I've been writing a simple program that would swap integers or arrays using templates. I am not sure why, but when I try to run this program it shows me that the function is ambiguous, although function swapping arrays takes three arguments and the one swapping numbers takes 2.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<typename T>
void swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T dummy = a;
    a = b;
    b = dummy;
}
template<typename T>
void swap(T a[], T b[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
    {
        T dum = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = dum;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    int b = 10;
    swap(a, b);
    cout << "a: " << a << "\t" << "b: " << b << endl;
    
    int eights[] = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
    int threes[] = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        cout << eights[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        cout << threes[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    
    swap(eights, threes, 7);
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        cout << eights[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        cout << threes[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    
    
    


}
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `using namespace std;`. The ambiguity is in `std::swap`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you should do some changes to remove the ambiguity between the std::swap and yours. remove `using namespace std;` and use `std::` before `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T dummy = a;
    a = b;
    b = dummy;
}
template<typename T>
void swap(T a[], T b[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
    {
        T dum = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = dum;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    int b = 10;
    swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << "\t" << "b: " << b << std::endl;
    
    int eights[] = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
    int threes[] = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        std::cout << eights[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        std::cout << threes[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    
    swap(eights, threes, 7);
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        std::cout << eights[i] << "\t";
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        std::cout << threes[i] << "\t";
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, in your implementation (i.e. compiler and standard library) `<iostream>` brings in the standard algorithm `std::swap()` (which is declared in `<algorithm>`).     That behaviour is not required by the standard, but also not forbidden by it.

By using `using namespace std`,  candidates for resolving the call `swap(a, b)` are found both in namespace `std`, and in your templated `swap()`.     Both candidates can accept two arguments, and both have arguments of the same type, hence the ambiguity.

The fix is to remove your templated `swap()` that accepts two arguments.   To ensure portability of your code, add `#include <algorithm>`   (i.e. don't rely on `std::swap()` being available because of `#include <iostream>`, since that is not actually guaranteed).

Although not strictly necessary in your case, it is often considered advisable to avoid using `using namespace std` in your code.   If you *really* want to write your own templated function named `swap()`, removing `using namespace std` will help ensure your function does not introduce ambiguity with `std::swap()`.

Incidentally, if you are using C++11 or later, your three-argument `swap()` is also not necessary, since `<algorithm>` provides a `std::swap()` overload that can swap two raw arrays with any type of element (if the size is known at compile time).